# XHTML 1.1 Strict expand with <link sizes"">

Tags: validation, xhtml, doctype, dtd

Today I came across a new problem.

As most of you probably already know, the a:target="_blank" is not validate XHTML Strict. But today I wanted to add icons for iPod, iPhone and iPads to the website. The piece of code needed for this is:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo_144.png" sizes="144x144" />
```

As you probally guessed the attribute sizes isn't valid either. The biggest problem is XHTML1.1 is a must. So I can't go to HTML5 or transitional. I found out I could use a custom DTD, which isn't preferred. I also found out it is possible to add a few custom DTD lines to expand the original. The code was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" [
    <!ATTLIST link sizes CDATA #IMPLIED >
]>
```

This, which obviously did not do the job, printed ']>' right into the page, given me more errors such as no charset. I tried to change 'PUBLIC' into 'SYSTEM' without any luck.

Is there a right way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a right way to do this?

No.

You can either use XHTML 1.1 (there is no such thing as XHTML 1.1 Strict) or you can use something with a `sizes` attribute on the `link` element.

If you use a custom DTD, then you aren't using XHTML 1.1 any more (you are using your custom language).

Comment: Too bad, I thought it was possible because some people use the method above with XHTML 1.0 Transitional. And wasn't XHTML 1.1 always strict? Next thing, when I add the line to the DTD itself, it still validates as XHTML 1.1.

Comment: When that technique gets used, it stops being XHTML 1.0 Transitional or XHTML 1.1 and becomes Some Custom Language.

Comment: XHTML 1.1 takes XHTML 1.0 Strict as a starting point, but it isn't called Strict (because there is no need to distinguish it from the non-existent XHTML 1.1 Transitional and XHTML 1.1 Frameset)

Comment: That is very clear. But even when I try it like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/dtd_developing.html (bottom of the page) I still get the same error. So it even isn't possible when I use a custom DTD and add the code inline?

Comment: Not with some common tag soup parsers. HTML 5 gives up on the idea of DTDs due to lack of support for SGML/XML from browsers.

Comment: @Quentin HTML5 not using DTDs has nothing to do with browser support for XML. HTML5 has an XML serialization, that's fully supported by all popular browsers including IE. DTDs are no longer used because they're superseded by Schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use type instead of sizes.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="72x72" href="/theme/mobile/72x72.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two correct ways to go about doing this, depending on your preference.

Your above example looks correct, I'm not sure which browser you were trying that was printing the `]>` - it could perhaps be the extra space at the end of the ATTLIST:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" [
    <!ATTLIST link sizes CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

The other - probably slightly easier - option is to opt for [the XML serialization of HTML5 (often called XHTML5)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax); as the size attribute has been added in HTML5 it would seem to make most sense. Using this you can exclude the doctype altogether as the [HTML5 validator opts for RELAX NG Schema for validation purposes instead of DTDs](http://about.validator.nu/#no-dtd), but it is generally recommended to leave the doctype in for general portability and compatibility with IE8 and below using a [HTML5 Polyglot](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-xhtml-author-guide/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to suppress the attribute sizes validation error inorder to validate the rest of the document, you could insert `<!ATTLIST link sizes CDATA #IMPLIED>` on the fly while validating. Here's an `xmllint` example:

```
sed '/<!DOCTYPE/ {
        s/\([^>]*\)/\1 [<!ATTLIST link sizes CDATA #IMPLIED>]/
    }
    ' input.html | \
xmllint --noout --valid - 2>/dev/null || \
echo "Not valid: input.html"
```